# How to read array of struct columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let my schema of table is as

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Genere: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Happy: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Horror: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Adventure: integer (nullable = true)
```

Happy , Horror and Adventure will have 1 or 0 value 
I want to make a function in which I am checking in row and Outputing a sequence Which contains 1 in that Row

example

```
def getOnlyPresentGenere(row:  Row): Seq[String] = {
some code
}
```

Example

```
+-------+-----------+
|name   |    genere |
+-------+-----------+
|   mile|[[1, 0, 1]]|
|  Tyson|[[0, 1, 0]]|
+-------+-----------+
```

for Row 1 `getOnlyPresentGenere` will return a sequence of `Seq("Happy","Adventure")`
for Row 2 `getOnlyPresentGenere` wil return `Seq("Horror")`

i basically want `getOnlyPresentGenere` like How we can write and Extract sequence Basically I even dont know the Genere like if it has Happy , Horror and Adventure so I dont want by hardcoding of these column names the only column name which I know is Genre

Comment: can you add expected output ?

Comment: I have added its Seq[String] . please see getOnlyPresentGenere output

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
    def getOnlyPresentGenere(r: Row): Seq[String] = {
      @tailrec
      def loop(arr: Array[Int], index: Int, value: Int, acc: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
        // [Happy, Horror, Adventure]
        index match {
          case 0 if value == 1 => loop(arr,index + 1, arr(index + 1), acc :+ "Happy" )
          case 1 if value == 1 => loop(arr, index + 1, arr(index + 1), acc :+ "Horror")
          case 2 if value == 1 => acc :+ "Adventure"
          case 2 if value == 0 => acc
          case _ => loop(arr, index + 1, arr(index + 1), acc)
        }
      }
      val array = r(1).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Int]].toArray
      loop(array,0,array(0),Seq())
    }

      import spark.implicits._

      val data = sc
        .parallelize(Seq(("Mile", Array(1, 0, 1)), ("Tyson", Array(0, 1, 0))))
        .toDF("name", "genere")

      val genere = data.rdd.map(r => getOnlyPresentGenere(r))

      genere.foreach(println)
```

output

```
List(Happy, Adventure)
List(Horror)
```

You can try this way too

```
  type Happy = Integer
  type Horror = Integer
  type Adventure = Integer

  case class Genere(happy:Happy , horror: Horror, adventure: Adventure) {
    def getHappy:String = if(happy== 1) "Happy" else ""
    def getHorror: String = if(horror == 1) "Horror" else ""
    def getAdventure: String = if(adventure == 1) "Adventure" else ""
  }
  case class Favourite(name: String, genere: Genere)

  def getOnlyPresentGenere(fav: Favourite): Seq[String] = {
      val gen = fav.genere
      Seq(gen.getHappy, gen.getHorror, gen.getAdventure).filter(!_.equals(""))
    }

      import spark.implicits._
      val fav1 = Favourite("Mile",Genere(1, 0, 1) )
      val fav2 = Favourite("Tyson", Genere(0,1,0))
      val data: Dataset[Favourite] = sc
        .parallelize(Seq(fav1, fav2))
        .toDS.as[Favourite]

      data.printSchema()

      val genere = data.map( (r: Favourite) => getOnlyPresentGenere(r))
      genere.show()
```

output

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- genere: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- happy: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- horror: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- adventure: integer (nullable = true)

+------------------+
|             value|
+------------------+
|[Happy, Adventure]|
|          [Horror]|
+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks but in my case I dont know the column  Happy Horror and Adventure as these columns are dynamic and can be change so I want to code for dyanmic column name not like hard coding them

Comment: Then tell me how do you know what a 1 represent at any moment, how do you know?

Comment: From schema the schema is same

Comment: But the schema can change frequenctly so insstead of hardcoding can you help me do to dynamic thing . It will also help you to know new thing

Comment: I added a new way, I hope it gives you some clues.